# combine and save images in c++

Tags: image, visual-c++

I have some [bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and I would like to save them to a single image with a given number of images in a column and row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bitmap the size of the overall total. Load each source bitmap in turn, blit it to the appropriate location in the combined bitmap. Save the combined bitmap.

Saving the composite is probably the most tedious of these steps, (you need to create and fill in a `BITMAPFILEHEADER` followed by a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, `BITMAPV4HEADER` or `BITMAPV5HEADER`), but none of it is particularly difficult and Google should turn up lots of examples.